# php: how to get single value from a comma(,) separated array

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have applied tags functionality in my project just like stack overflow.

When i subit multiple tags from my form, and in my controller
 i am getting it like this:

`$this->input->post('tags_id')`  so i am getting  `2,3,44,442` as the value for  `$this->input->post('tags_id')`  altogether.

**What i want is** i want the each value to be inserted into my tags table one by one.

How can i get the each value from from the comma separated list to be inserted in my db?
Please help me...

I am doing the following to insert into my db

```
  function entry_insert_instdetails()
{ 
   $this->load->database();     
   $this->db->trans_begin();  
   $data=array('instrunction'=> $this->input->post('tags_id'),   
   'creater_id'=>$this->session->userdata('userid'), 
    ); 
    $this->db->insert('instructions',$data); 

  if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
    }  
  else 
    {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: check the [explode](http://www.php.net/explode) function. splits a string into an array. [str_getcsv](http://php.net/str_getcsv) does the same for comma seperated values (csv) with some special functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily with explode function of php

```
$data   =   array('instrunction'=> $this->input->post('tags_id');

$ids    =   explode(',',$data);

unset($data);

foreach($ids as $id)
{
    $data['tag_id'] =   $id;    // tag_id is table column
    $this->db->insert('instructions',$data);
    unset($data);
}
```